Control or Method to Display a WebRTC Video Stream in WPF
I'm working on a C# WPF application using .NET 8, and I'm trying to display a WebRTC video stream efficiently. Currently, I’m using VideoView from LibVLC, but the stream doesn't display as expected. I’m looking for the most efficient way to render WebRTC video in WPF. I've read about different approaches, such as MediaElement, WriteableBitmap, and VideoView, but I’m unsure which is best for smooth playback and minimal latency with WebRTC in WPF.
Here’s the code I’m currently using. This example sets up a WebRTC connection, receives video frames, and attempts to display them in a VideoView:
public async Task Main(VideoView videoView, int cameraIndex, CancellationToken token, string cameraUrl)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Starting WebRTC connection setup.");

    _libVLC = new LibVLC();
    _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(_libVLC);
    _videoView = videoView;

    // Assign MediaPlayer when _videoView is fully loaded
    _videoView.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
    {
        _videoView.MediaPlayer = _mediaPlayer;
        Debug.WriteLine("MediaPlayer set on VideoView.");
    };

    await StartSocket(cameraIndex, token);
    await SendInitialRequest(cameraIndex, cameraUrl, token);
    await InitializePeerConnection(cameraIndex, token);
    _ = Task.Run(() => ReceiveWebSocketMessages(cameraIndex, token));

    Debug.WriteLine("WebRTC connection setup complete.");
}

private async Task InitializePeerConnection(int cameraIndex, CancellationToken token)
{
    var config = new PeerConnectionConfiguration
    {
        IceServers = new List<IceServer>
        {
            new IceServer
            {
                Urls = new List<string> { "turn:localhost:3478" },
                TurnUserName = "testuser",
                TurnPassword = "testpassword"
            }
        }
    };

    pc = new PeerConnection();
    await pc.InitializeAsync(config);
    Debug.WriteLine("PeerConnection initialized.");

    // Configure the transceiver for receiving video
    var videoTransceiver = pc.AddTransceiver(MediaKind.Video);
    videoTransceiver.DesiredDirection = Transceiver.Direction.ReceiveOnly;

    // Event for handling the remote video track
    pc.VideoTrackAdded += async (RemoteVideoTrack track) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Remote video track added.");

        // Here, frame processing logic can be added if we want debug info.
        track.I420AVideoFrameReady += frame =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Frame received - Width: {frame.width}, Height: {frame.height}");
        };

        // Play once MediaPlayer and VideoView are initialized
        if (!_mediaPlayer.IsPlaying)
        {
            _mediaPlayer.Play();
            Debug.WriteLine("MediaPlayer started.");
        }
    };
}

Problem:
The frames are received from the WebRTC stream (as confirmed by logging), but they don't display in the VideoView.
Questions:

Is VideoView the best choice for displaying WebRTC video in WPF, or should I be using a different control, such as MediaElement or WriteableBitmap?
Is there a more efficient method for directly displaying WebRTC streams in WPF that minimizes latency?
If VideoView is suitable, how can I ensure that it updates correctly with incoming WebRTC frames?

Any guidance, advice, or optimizations on displaying WebRTC video streams in WPF are appreciated! Thank you in advance for your help.
What I tried:

I initially used VideoView from the LibVLC library to render the WebRTC video stream, as shown in the code above. The MediaPlayer is set and plays, and I confirmed that the WebRTC frames are being received in the VideoTrackAdded event. However, the VideoView control itself doesn’t update or display the stream.
I also attempted calling _mediaPlayer.Play() in various places to ensure it was triggered, and I added debug statements to verify that frames are being received as expected.


If there is no audio with the video just convert frame to bitmapsource and bind an 's Source propterty to this bitmapsource
